# Regular expression to match all 4XX numbers except 400 and 411

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a bunch of 4XX status codes and I want to match all except 400 and 411.

What I currently have so far:

```
/4\d{2}(?!400|411)/g
```

Which according to regexer:

- Matches a 4XX
- Should specify a group that cannot match after the main expression (but it is here where my expression is failing).

Comment: It could be `4(?!00|11)\d{2}`

Comment: What is working and what not?

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `4\d{2}(?!400|411)` First matches a `4` and then 2 digits. After the matching, it asserts not 400 and 411 directly to the right.

Instead, you can match `4` and first assert not 00 or 11 directly after it.

```
4(?!00|11)\d{2}
```

Or without partial word matches using word boundaries `\b`:

```
\b4(?!00|11)\d{2}\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5h0fpw/1)

Answer (score 3):

If this is for a RegEx embedded in a programming language, I'd recommend using string comparisons or converting the status code to a number if it isn't already to then do number comparisons.

---

If you're forced to use RegEx, another, arguably less readable option (that does however make use of fewer RegEx features and is thus more portable): [`4(0[1-9]|[1-9][02-9])`](https://regex101.com/r/l648NQ/1)

- If the second character is a zero, the third character must be a nonzero digit;
- If the second character is a one, the third character must be any digit other than one

If you don't want/need a capturing group, change the RegEx to `4(?:...)`.